# Is there a grid system for the UI layout in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is anyone aware of a grid system in Dart that will host elements, etc?

I'm asking because I would like a grid that would allow the placement of elements using something like `setGrid(row, column)`.

Comment: You need to provide more info.  Are you using Angular or Polymer?  How are you creating the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using a CSS toolkit like Bootstrap:
http://www.getbootstrap.com/
It comes with a 12 column grid.  There's a version customized for Dart called Bootjack:
https://github.com/rikulo/bootjack

If you want a really small CSS framework with a Grid built in, there's always YUI's Pure:
https://github.com/yui/pure